# @ElementCollection does not getting detached

Tags: java, jpa

My goal is to clone entity 'Product' with all its filters.

For example, I have an entity (getters and setters omitted for simplicity):

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection()
    private List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
}
```

And embeddable class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Filter {
    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long variant = -1;
}
```

Now, if I do:

```
entityManager.detach(product);
product.setId(null);
productService.save(product);
```

I will get a copy of product entity but with filters from original product. In meanwhile original product will end up with no filters at all..

Thats how filter's table rows looks like:

Before:

```
product_id; name; variant
217; "f2"; 86
```

After:

```
product_id; name; variant
218; "f2"; 86
```

I tried detach each filter from the list but it gives me error.

How can I make it copy filters with an entity?

Edit: Added full Product and Filter code:

```
package com.serhiy1.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.SortableField;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.serhiy1.constraint.LocalePacker;

@Indexed
@Entity
@EntityListeners(ProductListener.class)
public class Product {
    public static final int PRICE_PER_ONE = 0;
    public static final int PRICE_PER_METER = 1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long code;

    private String name = "";

    private String grouping = "";

    @Field
    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String title = "";

    @Field
    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String intro = "";

    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String content = "";

    @Field
    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String contentHtml = "";

    private String locale = "en";

    private Long parentId = 0L;

    private DateTime time;

    private DateTime timeMod;

    private Long balanceRequired = 0L;

    private Integer index = 0;

    @Field(name = "price_sort")
    @SortableField(forField = "price_sort")
    private Double price = 0.0;

    private Integer pricePer;

    @Transient
    private long childrenCount = 0;
    @Transient
    private String image = "";
    @Transient
    private List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "category_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Product category;

    @ElementCollection()
    private List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    @ElementCollection()
    private List<Modifier> modifiers = new ArrayList<Modifier>();

    public Product() {
    }

    @Transient
    private String _title = "";
    @Transient
    private String _intro = "";
    @Transient
    private String _content = "";
    @Transient
    private String _contentHtml = "";

    public void pack(String locale, List<String> locales) {
        if(locale.contains("_")) return;
        title = LocalePacker.repack(locale, _title, title, locales);
        intro = LocalePacker.repack(locale, _intro, intro, locales);
        content = LocalePacker.repack(locale, _content, content, locales);
        contentHtml = LocalePacker.repack(locale, _contentHtml, contentHtml, locales);
    }
    public void unpack(String locale) {
        _title = LocalePacker.unpackStr(locale, title).getOrDefault(locale, "");
        _intro = LocalePacker.unpackStr(locale, intro).getOrDefault(locale, "");
        _content = LocalePacker.unpackStr(locale, content).getOrDefault(locale, "");
        _contentHtml = LocalePacker.unpackStr(locale, contentHtml).getOrDefault(locale, "");
    }
    public void copy(String landFrom, String landTo) {
        title = LocalePacker.copyLang(title, landFrom, landTo);
        intro = LocalePacker.copyLang(intro, landFrom, landTo);
        content = LocalePacker.copyLang(content, landFrom, landTo);
        contentHtml = LocalePacker.copyLang(contentHtml, landFrom, landTo);
    }

    public Modifier getModifier(String name) {
        for(Modifier m: modifiers) {
            if(m.getName().equals(name)) return m;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getCode() {
        return code == null ? id : code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGrouping() {
        return grouping;
    }

    public void setGrouping(String grouping) {
        this.grouping = grouping;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return _title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this._title = title;
    }

    public String getIntro() {
        return _intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(String intro) {
        this._intro = intro;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return _content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this._content = content;
    }

    public String getContentHtml() {
        return _contentHtml;
    }

    public void setContentHtml(String contentHtml) {
        this._contentHtml = contentHtml;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public long getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(long parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public DateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(DateTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public DateTime getTimeMod() {
        return timeMod;
    }

    public void setTimeMod(DateTime timeMod) {
        this.timeMod = timeMod;
    }

    public long getBalanceRequired() {
        return balanceRequired == null ? 0L : balanceRequired;
    }
    public void setBalanceRequired(long balanceRequired) {
        this.balanceRequired = balanceRequired;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        //return index == null ? 1000 : index;
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price == null ? 0.0 : price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPricePer() {
        return pricePer == null ? PRICE_PER_METER : pricePer;
    }
    public void setPricePer(int pricePer) {
        this.pricePer = pricePer;
    }

    public long getChildrenCount() {
        return childrenCount;
    }
    public void setChildrenCount(long childrenCount) {
        this.childrenCount = childrenCount;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Product getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Product category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Filter> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public List<Modifier> getModifiers() {
        return modifiers;
    }

    public void setModifiers(List<Modifier> modifiers) {
        this.modifiers = modifiers;
    }

    public boolean isCategory() { return price < 0; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Article{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

..

```
package com.serhiy1.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Embeddable
public class Filter {
    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long variant = -1;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getVariant() {
        return variant;
    }
    public void setVariant(long variant) {
        this.variant = variant;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you use ElementCollection on an embeddable holding columns from the same table?

Comment: What do you mean? An embeddable has two columns name and variant, Those does not appear elsewhere.

Comment: name and  variant are columns of Product table right?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski wanted to say it doesn't make sense to map Filter to the same table as Product.

Comment: ElementCollection is kind of OneToMany, but for non-entity types.

Comment: No, name and variant are columns of Filter table. Product has no other columns just for simplicity. One product can have multiple filters. The problem is that they are getting transferred to clonned product instead of been clonned also...

Comment: Can you post the Product and Filter **exact** code?

Comment: Sure, though they are very bloated with other stuff. Should I post them separately somewhere at the bottom?

Comment: Ok .............

Comment: Did that. Not sure if it helps though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mini project trying to replicate your issue.

It is a String Boot project with H2 database and JPA (Hibernate implementation).

On startup, Hibernate creates 2 tables:

```
create table product (
   id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

and

```
create table product_filters (
   product_id bigint not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    variant bigint not null
)
```

On product with filters creation, both tables get inserted:

```
insert 
into
    product
    (id) 
values
    (1)
```

and

```
insert 
into
    product_filters
    (product_id, name, variant) 
values
    (1, "f1", 1)
```

After:

```
entityManager.detach(product);
product.setId(null);
productService.save(product);
```

Hibernate issues:

```
delete 
from
    product_filters 
where
    product_id=1
```

which is normal, since `filters` is an ElementCollection therefore it is totally owned by the entity `Product`. On `productService.save(product)` Hibernate detects that `filters` collection is bound to another `Product` therefore deletes the old bound (from `product_filter` table) before creating a new one.

The only way to overcome the deletion is to recreate the collection:

```
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>(); 
    filters.addAll(oldFilters);
    product.setFilters(filters);
```

To sum up, here is the solution:

```
// To trigger the fetch
List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>(product.getFilters());
entityManager.detach(product);
product.setId(null);
product.setFilters(filters);
productService.save(product);
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this but if I insert your code before 'entityManager.detach(product);' it changes nothing. If I insert your code after, it gives me exception:

Comment: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.serhiy1.model.Product.filters, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Huh thanks, I just made it work by placing your initial code before the detach and 'product.setFilters(filters);' after ;-)

Comment: @minyor That's because the entity `product` is detached, it can't trigger the fetch. See my updated answer.